# what does it mean for 'threshold the data'?

Tags: data-mining

I came across a online data mining course project

http://www.kdnuggets.com/data_mining_course/assignments/final-project.html

The data is of samples with 7000 features as genes. Each gene is associated with a value. Some of the values are negative. The data looks like in this way:

SNO "U48730_at" "U58516_at" "U73738_at" "X06956_at" "X16699_at" "X83863_at"

X1   "  27"      " 161"      "   0"      "  34"      "   2"      " 116"
X2   "  27"      " 265"      "   0"      "  98"      "   2"      " 123"
X3   "  24"      " 126"      "   0"      "  21"      "   0"      " 142"
X4   "  27"      " 163"      "  -1"      "  16"      "  -1"      " 134"
X5   "  41"      " 138"      "   1"      "  29"      "   1"      " 153"
X6   "  55"      " 107"      "  -1"      "  17"      "   0"      " 152"
X7   "  27"      "  99"      "   0"      "  57"      "   1"      " 139"
X8   "   2"      " 137"      "  -1"      "  19"      "  -3"      " 213"
X9   "   -5"     "  161"     "   -3"     "   23"     "    2"     "  193"
X10  "   0"      " 110"      "  -3"      "   7"      "  -1"      " 208"
X11  "  -7"      "  67"      "   1"      "   2"      "  -2"      " 149"
X12  "   4"      "  93"      "   3"      "  37"      "   2"      " 266"
X13  "    2"     "   75"     "    3"     "   30"     "    6"     "  205"

The professor advise the students to first do 'data cleaning'. The original sentence is 
 Threshold both train and test data to a minimum value of 20, maximum of 16,000.

I first thought that it is to search over each gene and if there is a value out of the bounds, then just discard this gene as a feature. However, it seems for every gene, there must be a sample with the value out of bound.

What should I do by "threshold this data"? Is that like if the value is below 20, then set it 20 or if the value is above 16000, then just set it as 16000?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: should be on stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, I will ask people there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your last supposition is true; values outside the range 20..16000 should be set to those values.

If every piece of data has values outside of that range, then it probably wouldn't make sense to exclude it.

Try it and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks. I also sought the similar topic and see a few people are doing the same thresholding work.